# Subtract a batch of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am transitioning to using pandas for handling my csv datasets. I am currently trying to do in pandas what I was already doing very easily in numpy: subtract a group of columns from another group several times. This is effectively a element-wise matrix subtraction.

Just for reference, this used to be my numpy solution for this

```
def subtract_baseline(data, baseline_columns, features_columns):
    """Takes in a list of baseline columns and feature columns, and subtracts the baseline values from all features"""
    assert len(features_columns)%len(baseline_columns)==0, "The number of feature columns is not divisible by baseline columns"
    num_blocks = len(features_columns)/len(baseline_columns)    
    block_size = len(baseline_columns)                         
    for i in range(num_blocks):
        #Grab each feature block and subract the baseline
        init_col = block_size*i+features_columns[0]
        final_col = init_col+block_size
        data[:, init_col:final_col] = numpy.subtract(data[:, init_col:final_col], data[:,baseline_columns])
    return data
```

To ilustrate better, we can create the following toy dataset:

```
data = [[10,11,12,13,1,10],[20,21,22,23,1,10],[30,31,32,33,1,10],[40,41,42,43,1,10],[50,51,52,53,1,10],[60,61,62,63,1,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['L1P1','L1P2','L2P1','L2P2','BP1','BP2'],dtype=float)

   L1P1  L1P2  L2P1  L2P2   BP1   BP2
0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0   1.0  10.0
1  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0   1.0  10.0
2  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0   1.0  10.0
3  40.0  41.0  42.0  43.0   1.0  10.0
4  50.0  51.0  52.0  53.0   1.0  10.0
5  60.0  61.0  62.0  63.0   1.0  10.0
```

The correct output would be the result of grabbing the values in L1P1 & L1P2 and subtracting G1P1 & G1P2 (AKA the baseline), then doing it again for L2P1, L2P2 and any other columns there might be (this is what my for loop does in the original function).

```
   L1P1  L1P2  L2P1  L2P2   BP1   BP2
0   9.0   1.0  11.0   3.0   1.0  10.0
1  19.0  11.0  21.0  13.0   1.0  10.0
2  29.0  21.0  31.0  23.0   1.0  10.0
3  39.0  31.0  41.0  33.0   1.0  10.0
4  49.0  41.0  51.0  43.0   1.0  10.0
5  59.0  51.0  61.0  53.0   1.0  10.0
```

Note that labels for the dataframe should not change, and ideally I'd want a method that relies on the columns indexes, not labels, because the actual data block is 30 columns, not 2 like in this example. This is how my original function in numpy worked, the parameters baseline_columns and features_columns were just lists of the columns indexes.

After this the baseline columns would be deleted all together from the dataframe, as their function has already been fulfilled.

I tried doing this for just 1 batch using iloc but I get Nan values

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1]] = df.iloc[:,[0,1]] - df.iloc[:,[4,5]]

   L1P1  L1P2  L2P1  L2P2  G1P1  G1P2
0   NaN   NaN  12.0  13.0   1.0  10.0
1   NaN   NaN  22.0  23.0   1.0  10.0
2   NaN   NaN  32.0  33.0   1.0  10.0
3   NaN   NaN  42.0  43.0   1.0  10.0
4   NaN   NaN  52.0  53.0   1.0  10.0
5   NaN   NaN  62.0  63.0   1.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.values` at the end , pandas dataframe will search the column and index match to do the subtract , since the column is not match for 0,1 and 4,5 it will return NaN

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1]]=df.iloc[:,[0,1]].values - df.iloc[:,[4,5]].values
df
Out[176]: 
   L1P1  L1P2  L2P1  L2P2  BP1   BP2
0   9.0   1.0  12.0  13.0  1.0  10.0
1  19.0  11.0  22.0  23.0  1.0  10.0
2  29.0  21.0  32.0  33.0  1.0  10.0
3  39.0  31.0  42.0  43.0  1.0  10.0
4  49.0  41.0  52.0  53.0  1.0  10.0
5  59.0  51.0  62.0  63.0  1.0  10.0
```

Comment: Worked like I needed once I replaced the hardcoded columns to ranges! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to do it in one line? I.e. would it be okay for your purposes to do it with two lines:

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0] - df.iloc[:,4]
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1] - df.iloc[:,5]
```

These two lines achieve what I think is your intent.